# Creating a simple MDM server - Ruby

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mdm

I am trying to build a Mobile Devise Management Server for iOS devises.

How to build the MDM server on our own?

I have been following the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/7-MDMVendorCSRSigningOverview/MDMVendorCSRSigningOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017387-CH6-SW11. But the code snippets are in .NET and java.

I have also read about https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server . But this is built using java and python.

I need the backend to be in Ruby. Is there any proper documentation which could shed some light on this?
where should I start and are there any ruby code snippets available?

Comment: I evaluated lot of servers and 3rd party services (like cisco meraki etc) for MDM in past. I didn't find anything good implemented in Ruby. The best one I came across is in Go - https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm. It really gets the work done and has lot of features.

Comment: Infact, my use case was also to use in a ruby application. I ended up using Micromdm as a standalone server and communicating in Ruby app via http calls and redis pub-sub.